# How to display all photos from the cache?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an application where I can take a photo on screen number 1. I need to display all photos on screen number two.

Or how to display all the photos that are on the way
`data/user/0/com.example.geo/cache/` after the cache, you need to substitute the names of the photos, but I can’t know them in advance

I am trying to do it like this -

```
Image.file(File('data/user/0/com.example.geo/cache/'[index])
```

but, I don't understand how to substitute all the values. I also get an error -

```
Cannot open file, path = 't' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
or
Cannot open file, path = 'a' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
or
Cannot open file, path = 'd' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

The path is correct, because if you add the name of the photo after /cache, then it will be displayed.
Please tell me how can I list ALL photos from the cache

full code -

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 5, //how to specify here "all files along 
                //the path data/user/0/com.example.geo/cache/" ??
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return
              Container(
              width: 300,
              height: 300,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Image.file(File('data/user/0/com.example.geo/cache/'), fit: BoxFit.fill,),
            );
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is incorrect. You have to the concatenate the string path properly:

```dart
Image.file(File('data/user/0/com.example.geo/cache/' + index.toString()), fit: BoxFit.fill,),
```

Comment: No. I have error - 'The argument type List<int> can't be assigned to the parameter type String'
if i use "+ [index]"

Comment: @Daniil updated the answer. check now.

Comment: cannot open file, path = 'data/user..../cache/0 (OS error: no such file or directory, errno = 2)

Comment: otherwise i can use "data/.....cache/$index", but isn't working